# Qr Code generating with ZXING library

Tags: android, eclipse, barcode, qr-code, zxing

I am new for android eclipse,and i want to know how to configure or use to generat the QR code from zxing library ,a open source from zxing team.,If any alternative is there pls also inform me.

So can anyone suggest me how should proceed ?

Comment: The example shown at the moment is correct and shows encoding. (I don't see an edit in between.)

Answer (score 4):

Copied from working code:

```
    String theDataToDisplay = "Hello World!";

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE");
        intent.putExtra("ENCODE_TYPE", "TEXT_TYPE" );
        intent.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA", theDataToDisplay );
        intent.putExtra("ENCODE_FORMAT", "QR_CODE");
        intent.putExtra("ENCODE_SHOW_CONTENTS", false );
        startActivity(intent);
```

This requires the BarCodeScanner to be installed on the device. Make sure you try/catch this code in case the package is missing.

Comment: ..i am developing application for the android ,so that i tagged to android..ok...

Comment: @323go..ok forget all that ...and help me in my following question

Comment: i want to use zxing lib. to generate qr code i am also trying to use http://zxing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java    this class but i got error like " 12-08 00:36:49.173: E/AndroidRuntime(310): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN (has extras) }
"....so can u suggest me what should i do

Comment: Read the answer I provided: "This requires the BarCodeScanner to be installed on the device. Make sure you try/catch this code in case the package is missing."

Answer (score 1):

Check out this class: [Intents.java](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/Intents.java)

That is the class that handles the ZXing intent.

You need to create an intent with `ACTION = "com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE"`

then add extras to it representing the data you want to encode, and the format/type of QR you want.

Another option that you have if using internet is ok is to use the [Google Image Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/) to generate them for you to download and display within your own activity. *Note: the API is depracated but may be functional until 2015*

Comment: how can i use direct zxing api in eclipse for generate barcode?

Answer (score 1):

The `IntentIntegrator` class provided by the project wraps up the `Intent`-based solutions described above. It's even easier that way.

See http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Though the examples concern scanning / decoding, the class itself has methods for encoding which work similarly.

Comment: thnx,but i want to know about how to generate QR code form zxing lib.,?

Comment: Not by `Intent`? are you sure? it's a lot more trouble. Look inside the core library, in `core/`. You will find an `Encoder` class inside the `.qrcode` package. If you look at the source code of Barcode Scanner in `android/`, you can find some usage of it as a guide.

Comment: thnx Sean, no,if it is possible by using intent i am ready to use it,so show me some code based on intent

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java